# How to write the CPLEX solution to excel

Tags: excel, cplex

I have a MIP problem giving me 3 solutions in CPLEX. How do I take one of those solutions and export it to an excel file?

I tried the following so far:
This is what I typed in CPLEX command prompt window

```
read try
optimize
display solution member
Display which solution: 1
variables
-

write try2
sol
Incumbent solution written to file 'try2'.   <-- OUTPUT ON SCREEN
```

This is an unknown format of file. I don't know what it is.
I want an excel file.

Comment: @SagarV see the edit

Comment: While posting in future, try to add the code you have tried so far. **Vote reversed (1+)**

Comment: Just try looking at the file in a text editor. I think it is an XML file format or similar. You can probably find or write a simple import function in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to export from CPLEX a file that Excel would be able to read.

As @TimChippingtonDerrick mentioned, the `.sol` file format that CPLEX will use when writing a solution is an XML file. This format is documented in [1], and its schema appears in CPLEX installations as `[InstallDir]/cplex/include/ilcplex/solution.xsd`

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/SOL.html